# Creating default pointcut spring aop

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-aop

While to utilise the AOP to authorize request in my controllers, I used the approach that

there is default validation and specfic validation, so that the request for which I don't have specfic pointcut defined they are authorized by the default approach.

```
 @Before("execution(* com.example.controller.ExampleController.*(..))")
  public void validate() {
    validatePermissions("user", "create");
  }

 @Before("execution(* com.example.controller.*.*(..))")
  public void validateUser() {
    validatePermissions("admin", "admin");
  }
```

Problem is that even though I have **specfic validation defined** for User case Its even in case of request to my Example controller request is **always going to default one.**

**what I want is that only request not already covered by other pointcut should go to the default pointcut**

Comment: Please mark kriegaex's as the accepted answer. That answer mentions the correct way of doing the generic and specific advises. Mine is about ordering and that is not what you want. Sorry for misguiding .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would make the specific pointcut(s) reusable and reference them in `&& !specificPointcut()` conditions, roughly like this (untested, just written in the browser):

```java
@Pointcut("execution(* com.example.controller.ExampleController.*(..))")
public void specificPointcut() {}

@Before("specificPointcut()")
public void validate() {
  validatePermissions("user", "create");
}

@Before("execution(* com.example.controller.*.*(..)) && !specificPointcut()")
public void validateUser() {
  validatePermissions("admin", "admin");
}
```

You can easily extend that to multiple specific pointcuts, either serially or hierarchically, depending on your situation.

Serially excluding pointcuts would work like `&& !(specificPc1() || specificPc2())` and hierarchically by a more common level always excluding the next more specific one.

Comment: I got stuck with the ordering of aspects and completely misunderstood the question. This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

From the reference documentation : [Advice Ordering](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-ordering)

*When two pieces of the same type of advice (for example, two @After advice methods) defined in the same @Aspect class both need to run at the same join point, the ordering is undefined (since there is no way to retrieve the source code declaration order through reflection for javac-compiled classes). Consider collapsing such advice methods into one advice method per join point in each @Aspect class or refactor the pieces of advice into separate @Aspect classes that you can order at the aspect level via Ordered or @Order.*

Considering the ordering is undefined and two different PCDs target the same join point , it is not possible to have a fallback or default pointcut among these two.

You could order the aspects after collapsing them to separate `@Aspect` classes , check the state of authorization ( may be from a thread local variable) or from an agrument you can get hold of from the join point.